# How to use Navigation.showOverlay(...) from react-native-navigation lib correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, wix-react-native-navigation

How to use Navigation.showOverlay(...) from react-native-navigation lib correctly?

If I had one Screen with just a single button which opens the Overlay and a second Screen with an Image component which should be shown in the Overlay.

I have read the playground examples of the lib, but I don't understand how I pass my second Screen as parameter to the showOverlay function correctly.

Could anyone provide a simple example? Thank you.

App.js:

```
import React, {} from 'react';
import {View, Button} from 'react-native';
import {Navigation} from 'react-native-navigation';
import OverlayScreen from './OverlayScreen';

const App = () => {

    const onButtonPressed = () => {
        Navigation.showOverlay(OverlayScreen);
    }

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Button onPress={onButtonPressed()}/>
    </View>
    );
};

export default App;
```

OverlayScreen.js:

```
import React, {} from 'react';
import {View, Image} from 'react-native';

const OverlayScreen = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Image 
            source={require('../assets/overlay.png')} 
            style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', height: 250, width: 250}}
        />
    </View>
    );
};

export default OverlayScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

Any type of layout can be displayed as an overlay. If you'd like to show a single component, use the following layout declaration:

```
Navigation.showOverlay({
  component: {
    name: 'OverlayScreen'
  }
});
```

Be sure to also register that component as a screen:

```
Navigation.registerComponent('OverlayScreen', () => OverlayScreen);
```